# Tensorflow estimator.DNNClassifier not repeating results

Tags: python, repeat, tensorflow-estimator

Each time I run the following code I get a different 'Loss for final step' when training my model. The subsequent evaluation accuracy also changes. I have checked that the input data from train_test_split is constant.I have set the value of tf.random_seed, turned off shuffling and set the value of num_threads. I am using Tensorflow 1.8. Can anyone advise me on what else I need to do?`

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

np.random.seed(1)
tf.set_random_seed(1)

df = pd.read_csv('diabetes.csv')
X = df.iloc[:,0:8]
y = df['Outcome']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3,
                                   stratify=None, random_state=1)

def create_feature_cols():
  return [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Pregnancies'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Glucose'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('BloodPressure'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('SkinThickness'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Insulin'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('BMI'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('DiabetesPedigreeFunction'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Age')
  ]

input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_train,y=y_train,
             batch_size=10,num_epochs=1000,shuffle=False,num_threads=1)
model  =  tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[20,20],
          feature_columns=create_feature_cols(),n_classes=2)
model.train(input_fn=input_func,steps=1000)

eval_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
      x=X_test,
      y=y_test,
      batch_size=10,
      num_epochs=1,
      shuffle=False,
      num_threads=1)
results = model.evaluate(eval_input_func)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that TensorFlow sent me to solve the problem. Rather than use tf.set_random_seed, with estimators you use tf.estimator.RunConfig.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(tf_random_seed=234)

input1_col = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('input1')
input2_col = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('input2')
model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[20,20],
feature_columns=[input1_col, input2_col],n_classes=2,config=config)

import numpy as np
input1 = np.random.random(size=(100, 1))
input2 = np.random.random(size=(100, 1))
target = np.where(np.sum(input1 + input2, axis = 1) > 0, 1, 0)
def train_input_fn():
return ({'input1': input1, 'input2': input2}, target)

model.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps = 10)
```